# Getting the whole array as one variable in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm having trouble with getting all the elements of the array as one. I want to write a program, that prints all the numbers that have both of those things going:

1. They have 3 digits,
2. When you take each digit to power of 3, then add the 3 numbers that you got together, you get the number you had in the beginning.

I can do it without arrays, but I'd like to know how to use them to do it. Is there any smart way to do so? 
I was thinking about something like this:

```
char tab[3];

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
        tab[0] = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            tab[1] = j;
            for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++){
                tab[2] = k;
            }
        }
    }
```

But what to do next?

Comment: Note that 3 to the power of 3 isn't 9, but 27.

Comment: Ooops right, sorry, but it doesn't really matter, you got my point anyway!

Comment: And 1 + 27 + 125 isn't 135 ;)

Comment: Yes I know, the example is not the number that I'm talking about, I was just trying to explain the mechanism, cause I weren't sure if what I said was clear, since I can only speak well about programming and maths in my native language.

Answer (score 1):

After you set `tab[2]` equal to `k` and before you end the inner loop, check if the three-digit number corresponding to `tab[0]`, `tab[1]`, and `tab[2]` meets your second requirement. If it does, print it.

So that means you need to compare the sum of the digits cubed, that is:

```
tab[0]*tab[0]*tab[0] + tab[1]*tab[1]*tab[1] + tab[2]*tab[2]*tab[2]
```

To the number, that is:

```
tab[0]*100 + tab[1]*10 + tab[2]
```

But there's really no good reason to use an array here. Using three integers would probably make things simpler. In fact, you're already storing the digits in `i`, `j`, and `k`, so why store a separate copy of each one in an array?

Comment: Yes, I got it but how to print it? Just with "printf("%d%d%d", tab[0], tab[1], tab[2])"? I was wondering if there is a way to print the whole array.

Comment: The thing is it is my homework. I did it without arrays and it is a very short program to be honest, but they tell me to use arrays in some smart way (since it's a new thing).

Comment: in plain C there is no other way to print "whole" array

Comment: Okay, thank you, I feel like I searched the whole web and couldn't find a thing.

Comment: I don't really know what they're expecting you to do since they're asking you to solve a problem in an unnatural way. You could write generic functions that take an array and its size and print the array as a multi-digit number, compute the sum of the cubes of the entries, and so on, then call those functions. Maybe that's what you're supposed to do, maybe not.

Comment: I don't either, I think I will just leave it without arrays and pretend it's all good.
Will you be this nice and help me with two other things about arrays?
a) How to sort elements in arrays from the smallest to the biggest number?
b) How do I make the program choose a random number from some certain compartment? Like <1, 2> or non-negative integers?

Comment: For `a`, you can do it however you want. A simple bubble sort is the easiest way. Basically, you write a function to swap two array elements if they're in the wrong order, then keep passing over the array swapping adjacent elements in the wrong order until they're sorted. Punch "C array sort" into your favorite search engine.

Comment: For `b`, there's no one right way that covers all those cases. For `0` to `1`, you can convert an integer random number to a `float` and then divide by the maximum integer value of the random source. For 2 or greater, you can take a random number that ranges from 0 and add 2 to it. For non-negative, you can just multiply by -1 if it's negative. And so on.

Comment: Yes but how do I tell program to take a random number so it's different ech time the program runs?

Comment: Usually by executing `srand(time(NULL));` just once when the program starts.

Comment: Okay I will look up more about it. Thank you very much, you really helped a lot, have a nice day/night! :)